# Android SipDemo example: exception with IO sending request

Tags: android, voip

I tried to launch [SipDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html) on my Motorola xoom.

Registration process on server has completed well.
When I tried call to someone I have "SipException: IO Error sending request".

If I use [CSipSimple](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.csipsimple) with same account settings it works fine.

Have you any idea to resolve this trouble?

Thanks.

Comment: Right answer: In standard SipDemo example from Google wasn't setting domain of target user. It was leading to this error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird trick on Android: the OS is inspecting all SIP packets (on port 5060) and will block if the format is not correct with UDP I/O exception. So I would suggest to have a look at the SIP message.
Also make sure that you added network permission in your project manifest file.